# Java switch case statement issue

Tags: java, enums, case, switch-statement

I'm trying to use a switch statement in Android aplication,where I have to check if an integer is equal to some of the Enum's value.The code goes like this :

```
    public enum RPCServerResponseCode{


        E_INCORRECT_LOGIN(4001),                
        E_ACCOUNT_DISABLED(4002),
        E_ACCOUNT_NOT_ACTIVE(4003);


        private int value;
        private RPCServerResponseCode(int i) {
            this.value=i;
        }
        public static RPCServerResponseCode getByValue(int i) {
             for(RPCServerResponseCode dt : RPCServerResponseCode.values()) {
                 if(dt.value == i) {
                     return dt;
                 }
             }
             throw new IllegalArgumentException("No datatype with " + i + " exists");
         }

    }

}
```

And my switch statement looks like this :

```
int errorCode;
switch(errorCode){

            case  RPCServerResponseCode.E_INCORRECT_LOGIN :
            {
                    if (user.isAuthenticated)
                    {
                        // logout before login
                    }
                    break;
            }
            case RPCServerResponseCode.E_ACCOUNT_NOT_ACTIVE:  
            {
                if (user.isAuthenticated)
                {
                    //logout
                }
                break;
            }
        }

    }
```

But I get error saying this : "Type mismatch: cannot convert from RPCCommucatorDefines.RPCServerResponseCode to int".
Any suggestions how to solce that issue? Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Switch statement: number to enum value / 1002 = MyEnum.NewYorkID](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7162192/switch-statement-number-to-enum-value-1002-myenum-newyorkid)

Comment: Thanks for the comment.Actually I didn't saw that question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`errorcode` is `int`. Should be of type `RPCServerResponseCode`, so you could use something like:

```
switch (RCPServerResponseCode.getByValue(errorcode))
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to compare your `INT` error code to a `RPCServerResponseCode` instance - This isn't possible.  You need to use the method `getByValue` in your `RPCServerResponseCode` class to do the conversion for you.  After that, you can use the result (Which will be a `RPCServerResponseCode` instance) in your switch statement:

```
int errorCode;
RPCServerResponseCode responseCode = RPCServerResponseCode.getByValue(errorCode);

switch(responseCode){

            case  RPCServerResponseCode.E_INCORRECT_LOGIN :
            {
                    if (user.isAuthenticated)
                    {
                        // logout before login
                    }
                    break;
            }
            case RPCServerResponseCode.E_ACCOUNT_NOT_ACTIVE:  
            {
                if (user.isAuthenticated)
                {
                    //logout
                }
                break;
            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Java enums are fully-fledged objects and cannot be implicitly cast to integers.

This should work:

```
switch(RPCServerResponseCode.getByValue(errorCode)){
```

Answer (score 2):

you can say

```
int errorCode=4001;
RPCServerResponseCode code = RPCServerResponseCode.getByValue(errorCode);
switch(code){
...
}
```